# How do I build an old angularjs project? Have only package.json

Tags: angularjs, build

I have inherited an old project, which I believe is in AngularJS not Angular 2, that I cannot find a way to build/compile.

I have never used AngularJS/Angular before but I am experienced with Vuejs, npm, webpack etc.

I have the dist folder, all the pre-built assets-files, etc. but I cannot understand how to rebuild the project. I also have the package.json file which is:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.7.5",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.7.5",
    "angular-scroll": "^1.0.2",
    "angular-ui-grid": "^4.6.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^1.1.4",
    "ng-animated-scroll": "^1.5.0",
    "ng-dialog": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-image-input-with-preview": "^1.0.0",
    "ngmap": "^1.18.4",
    "normalize.css": "^3.0.3",
    "ui-select": "^0.19.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-translate": "^2.18.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
    "chai": "^3.4.0",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.1.0",
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "fs-walk": "0.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.11.1",
    "mocha": "^2.3.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "supports-color": "^3.1.2",
    "yargs": "^3.9.0"
  },
```

Since it's an old project do I still have to use `ng build` commands, or this is for newer Angular?
Maybe I should have a gulp or bower configuration?

I am not sure what to look for, any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just run `npm install` to install all project dependencies.
Then check in your `package.json` file for the scripts key and you should have some tasks to run your project. In the old times people used to build the project with Grunt but the most popular tool is Gulp (with or without webpack)

Comment: I have ran 'npm install' and it installs all packages without errors, I have no 'scripts' in my package.json file. The package.json has only the dependencies, just like I have pasted in my original question. 

Still haven't figured out how to build the project, so any more insight would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `gulpfile.js` in your root dir?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no gulpfile, no gruntfile, no webpack config. From my understanding there is definitely some configuration missing from the root of the project.
If I wanted to recompile the project (remember it's an old angularjs), what would be the appropriate tool? Gulp, webpack or something else?

Comment: Perhaps a bit late and you alreadty figured it out. But it seems like you would need to start your own build if none exists. I would recommend webpack, as the documentation is really well done and it is much simpler since for an angularjs app you mainly need default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

First use `npm install` command.
Then try using `ng build projectname --prod` command.

I hope his will work for you.

Comment: I have installed @angular/cli@12.0.1 globally and when I run the 'ng build' command I get an error:
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler'

Which if I understand correctly I have to install this package, but since this is not already included in package.json it means I don't need that and there is something I 'm missing?

Comment: Have you removed older version globally and node_modules  folder.. ? If not then run these commands: $ npm remove -g angular-cli  then install it again $ npm install -g @angular/cli@latest after this update the project using these commands: 1. $ npm rm -rf node_modules dist 2. $ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest 3. $ npm install If I have correctly understood your problem then I hope this will work for you.

Comment: I have run 'npm install' successfully but when I try to build the project I get:
" An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json' "

Comment: Run $ npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
if it don't resolve your issue then run these commands:
$ npm rm -rf node_modules
Delete package-lock.json file manually.
$ npm cache clean --force
$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
$ npm install -g npm@latest
$ npm install
$ npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular